# Lambda calculus expression reduction

Tags: lambda-calculus

I don't know the correct answer how this reduction should've be done.
Should I simply put λfx.fx in a place of m and λzy.zzy in a place of n?

`(λmnfx.mf(nfx) λfx.fx λzy.zzy)`

Comment: You're on the right track. Pay special attention to the names of the variables as there is another reduction which must be performed before you can apply terms.

Comment: (λfx.f(f(fx))) I've figured answer like that, is that correct? Please praise my effort with correct answer or solution because I'am dying out of this lambda :(

Answer (score 0):

You have placed parenthesis around the two final variables in the body. I don't see that right-associativity supported in the stated problem where the third abstraction is \zy.zzy  not \zy.z(zy).

I believe the answer is \fx.f(ffx) which is equivalent to \fx.f((ff)x).

Also, this is a duplicate question but I'm not sure how to link to the other one.