# Lambda calculus -reducing expression

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have following expression to reduce:

$(λmnfx.mf(nfx) λfx.fx λzy.zzy)$

After some substitutions i get the result:

$(λfx. f(f(f x)))$

Is it correct answer? If not, please tell me what is correct one so i could try to get into it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lambda calculus expression reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843372/lambda-calculus-expression-reduction)

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the variables straight, I'm going to do an alpha conversion to the first abstraction, replacing f with a and x with b which leaves me with...

```
\mnab.ma(nab) \fx.fx \zy.zzy
```

Note the third abstraction contains no parenthesis and is therefore equivalent to \zy.(zz)y but is not equivalent to \zy.z(zy)

The second abstraction will replace the m variable and the third abstraction will replace the n variable. The a and b variables are going to be part of the solution abstraction.

```
\ab.(\fx.fx)a((\zy.zzy)ab)
```

Now I resolve the \fx abstraction, replacing f with a and x with ((\zy.zzy)ab).

```
\ab.a((\zy.zzy)ab)
```

Finally, I resolve \zy, replacing z with a and y with b.

```
\ab.a(aab)
```

This is not the same as the answer you have provided because the parenthetical portion is equivalent to "((aa)b)", not "(a(ab))" which would make it a Church Numeral. The variables in Church Numeral abstractions are right associative. Are you certain the problem is stated correctly?